# While selecting an option from jquery select, its aligned to right,

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

As you see in picture after selecting option from dropdown its aligned to right.
Which gives me output like after apply:

```
                                7777                                
                                Rohit Pandey                        
                                6
```

Which is incorrect for me. Because space are appended on both side.

How to get these items aligned perfect after which i will get answer after submitting form:

```
7777
Rohit Pandey
6
```

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: That's not default behaviour. You have some CSS or non-breaking spaces in those fields which needs to be removed. Without seeing your HTML/CSS we can't help you any further than that

Comment: show your code please. if you are storing as string. just use .trim() on the values you are getting

Comment: where to use `.trim()`

Comment: After selecting from dropdown its getting right aligned.

Comment: which type of css can do this type of behaviour?

Comment: post your HTML, how is dropdown being populated. is it from database or hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `trim()`

```js
console.log($("#dropdown option:selected").text());
console.log($("#dropdown option:selected").text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">Choice
  <option value="1">     test</option>
  </select>
```